# How to unwatch a file for push notifications?

Tags: google-drive-api

I can't seem to find a way to unwatch a file to unsubscribe from the changes. Is it possible to `DELETE` a watch resource?

```
DELETE POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/watch/watchId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `channels.stop`: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/channels/stop

```
POST https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/channels/stop

{
  "id":<your channel's uuid>,
  "resourceId": <resource id>
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed the fact it's returning a `channel` resource.